# Invariant Violation Objects are not valid as react child (found: Error Invalid Argument "path")

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I ran into this problem, after implementing 'react-native-fetch-blob' to upload image in  Firebase Storage.

I tried running the code from  https://github.com/CodeLinkIO/Firebase-Image-Upload-React-Native. My code is as follows:

```
uploadImage(uri, mime = "image/jpg", userID) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const uploadUri = uri;
    let uploadBlob = null;

    const imageRef = firebase
      .storage()
      .ref("images")
      .child(userID);

    fs.readFile(uploadUri, "base64")
      .then(data => {
        return Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` });
      })
      .then(blob => {
        uploadBlob = blob;
        return imageRef.put(blob, { contentType: mime });
      })
      .then(() => {
        uploadBlob.close();
        return imageRef.getDownloadURL();
      })
      .then(url => {
        resolve(url);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}
```

But I am always getting the error where it says :

> Invariant Violation Objects are not valid as react child (found: Error  Invalid Argument  "path")

Any help regarding this issue?

**EDIT**
Here is the other render code.

```
    this.state.isLoading ? 
        <Spinner style={{flex:1, alignSelf: 'center'}} color='blue' />
    :
    <Container>
    <Content style={{margin:20}}>

        <Item>
            <Icon type="FontAwesome" active name='user' style={{ color :'#c5aa6a'}} />
            <Input 
                placeholder='Email' 
                onChangeText= { (text)=> { this.setEmailText(text) } } 
                value={this.state.email}/>
        </Item>

        <Item>
            <Icon type="FontAwesome" active name='key' style={{ color :'#c5aa6a'}} />
            <Input 
                secureTextEntry 
                placeholder='Password'
                onChangeText= { (text)=> { this.setPasswordText(text) } } 
                value={this.state.password}
                />
        </Item>

        <Item>
            <Icon type="FontAwesome" active name='key' style={{ color :'#c5aa6a'}} />
            <Input 
                secureTextEntry 
                placeholder='Confirm Password'
                onChangeText= { (text)=> { this.setRePasswordText(text) } } 
                value={this.state.re_password}
                />
        </Item>

        <Button bordered success  style={{ justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 20}} onPress = { ()=> this.verifyCredentials() } >
            <Text style={{color:'#c5aa6a'}}>Sign Up</Text>
        </Button>

        {
            !this.state.avatarUri ?
            <Icon type="FontAwesome" active name='user-circle' style={styles.photoPicker} onPress= { ()=> this.openCamera() } /> :
            <Image style={styles.avatarPicked}  source= {this.state.avatarUri}  />

        }

        { 
            this.state.error ? 
                <Text style= {{ color: '#ff0000', alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: 30}}>    {this.state.error}  </Text>
                :
                null
        }

    </Content>

    <Button transparent onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('login')} style={styles.buttonStyle} >
        <Text style={{color:'#c5aa6a'}}>I already have an account</Text>
    </Button>

    </Container>
```

**EDIT 2**

```
startSigningUp (email,password)
{
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(
        ()=> {

        const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        const userId = user.uid;

        this.setState({
            user
        })


        this.uploadImage(this.state.avatarUri.uri,userId).then((imageURL)=>{
            saveDatabase(userId,imageURL)
        }).catch((error)=>{
            this.setState({
                error,
                isLoading: false
            })
        })



        })

}
```

Comment: Do you mind also sharing a snippet of the code that has or is trying to render the component with the `path`?

Comment: Not rendering anything with the path. I am just trying to upload the photo but it is not working, and giving me the error. If the upload is successful, I navigate to the other screen.

Comment: Ok, be that as it may, the Invariant Violation error you shared is a react error that it is trying to render an Object (as opposed to a primitive like string/number, or JSX)  as a child of another component. It could be that something you called is supposed to return renderable content but it is receiving an Error object, i.e. `Error Invalid Argument "path"` instead. Your snippet of the `uploadImage` appears to match the github docs, so maybe this error is not coming from this code. Do you get a stacktrace of any sort? Line number where the error occurs?

Comment: Have you used uploadImage method in render() ?

Comment: The render method is up there. UPDATED!

Comment: Is that all of your render function? Can you also share function that calls and handles response for `uploadImage`?

Comment: Yes. I have done that too!

Comment: Mind dropping a `console.log('error', error);` right in the catch block? I suspect that error is going straight to your ui in your render function, the last bit in your Content container.